# Why am I getting this IllegalArgumentException exception when trying to inject services into an actor?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, guice

My code:

Global.scala - i just set it up so on startup, it sends the actor a quick  message. the exception is thrown from here; i verified that the injected services has been loaded.

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {
  override def onStart(app: Application): Unit = {
    val system = app.actorSystem
    system.actorOf(TempActor.props, TempActor.name) ! "hi hi"
  }
}
```

TempActor.scala

```
package actors

class TempActor @Inject() (
    @Named(TestServiceModuleNames.RedisService) redisService: StatusService
  , @Named(TestServiceModuleNames.DynamoDbService) dynamoDbService: StatusService
) extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case msg: Any =>
      log.info(s"the msg => $msg")
      context.system.shutdown()
  }
}

object TempActor extends NamedActor {
  override def name: String = this.getClass.getSimpleName
  override def props: Props = Props[TempActor]
}
```

TestServiceModule.scala - a guice module to load in the services that the actor needs, ive made sure to enable the module in the application.conf

```
package modules

class TestServiceModule extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {

  val configs = ConfigFactory.load()

  override def configure(): Unit = {

    bind(classOf[StatusService]).annotatedWith(Names.named(TestServiceModuleNames.RedisService)).toInstance(new RedisStatusServiceImpl(new RedisConfig(configs.getString("redis.host"), configs.getInt("redis.port"))))
    bind(classOf[StatusService]).annotatedWith(Names.named(TestServiceModuleNames.DynamoDbService)).toInstance(new DynamoDBStatusServiceImpl(Region.US_EAST_1, configs.getString("dynamo.db.endpoint"), configs.getString("dynamo.db.table.name.status")))
  }
}

object TestServiceModuleNames {
  final val RedisService = "RedisStatusService"
  final val DynamoDbService = "DynamoDbStatusService"
}
```

application.conf

```
redis.host="localhost"
redis.port=4242

dynamo.db.endpoint="http://localhost:8000"
dynamo.db.table.name.status="status"

play.modules {
  enabled += "modules.TestServiceModule"
}

play.akka.actor-system="warden"

akka {
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  loglevel = "DEBUG"
}
```

My objective is to have a play app with the backend processing handled by actors. Each actor will have certain dependencies on different services, I tried to inject those services using google Guice.

All I get when I start the app is the exception trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no matching constructor found on class actors.TempActor for arguments []
```

I'm not sure how to fix this exactly...

I am using Play 2.4.

Comment: Please put the relevant parts of the code in-line (i.e. not a link to github) so the question is self contained http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253915/what-to-do-with-links-to-github-gists-in-questions

Comment: @mattinbits oops, thought it would be cleaner that way. will update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line `override def props: Props = Props[TempActor]` is trying to invoke a zero argument constructor version of TempActor, where none exists. There is nothing in the Akka code behind Props that would allow it to understand that you're using Google Guice and create a TempActor accordingly.

You could do it with something like:

```
override def props: Props = Props[TempActor] = {
  Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new TestServiceModule());
  Props(injector.getInstance(TempActor.class))
}
```

Comment: looks like this would work! i was very close to just scrapping the built in guice/actor system from play and using my own custom one.

Comment: question: how would i go about testing the actor? since the injector is "hard coded" in the props, mocking the services would be impossible, no? and since it is in props, i would repeat this code all over my many many actors?

Comment: I know more about the Akka side than the Guice side, but you could pass the injector into the props method if that works better in your case?

Answer (score 2):

In the end, I went with what I felt worked.

I used the boiler plate code in https://github.com/rocketraman/activator-akka-scala-guice to generate the actors that had dependencies.

In the Play app itself, I'm not using the actorsystem/guice that Play has builtin, I generate my own injector and actor system in the global settings.

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  final val injector = Guice.createInjector(
    new ServiceModule(),
    new ConfigModule(),
    new AkkaModule(),
    new ActorModule()
  )

  final val actorSystem = injector.instance[ActorSystem]
  final val quartzScheduler = QuartzSchedulerExtension.get(actorSystem)
  final val configs = new ConfigProvider().get()

  override def onStart(app: Application): Unit = {
      // onstart logic
  }


  override def onStop(app: Application): Unit = {
    actorSystem.shutdown()
  }
}
```

The way I set up my project is have a main actor/supervisor which is generated the normal way via "actorSystem.actorOf(..., name)". My supervisor doesn't have any dependencies as its job is to take in requests and relay them to the appropriate child actor(which are created using rocketraman's code).